# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1 address = 0x0)

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am trying to create a simple card shuffling and dealing simulator. I am using a vector to represent a deck of 52 cards and each card is represented by the structure `BitCard` whose elements' space is memory is limited by bitfields. But when the constructor tries to access the vector, xCode throws a `BAD_ACCESS exception: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1 address = 0x0)`. I've done some research and found that this exception is linked with a null pointer but can't seem to figure out how to fix it. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct BitCard{
    unsigned face:4;
    unsigned color:1;
    unsigned suit:2;
};
class DeckOfCards {
public:
    static const int faces = 13;
    static const int colors = 2;
    static const int numberOfCards = 52;
    DeckOfCards();
    void shuffle();
    void deal();
private:
    vector <BitCard> deck={};
};
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards(){
    for (int i = 0; i <numberOfCards;++i){
        deck[i].face = i%faces;
        deck[i].suit = i/faces;
        deck[i].color = i/(faces*colors);
    }
}
void DeckOfCards:: shuffle(){
    for (int i = 0; i <numberOfCards;i++){
        int j = rand()%numberOfCards;
        BitCard tmp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = tmp;
    }
}
void DeckOfCards:: deal(){
    for (int k1 = 0, k2 = k1+numberOfCards/2;k1<numberOfCards/2-1;k1++,k2++)
    {
        cout << "Color:" << setw(3) << deck[k1].color
        << " Card:" << setw(3) << deck[k1].face
        << " Suit:" << setw(3) << deck[k1].suit
        << " Color:" << setw(3) << deck[k2].color
        << " Card:" << setw(3) << deck[k2].face
        << " Card:" << setw(3) << deck[k2].suit;
    }
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    DeckOfCards testDeck;
    testDeck.shuffle();
    testDeck.deal();

    return 0;
}
```

The exception is generated in line

```
deck[i].face = i%faces;
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an element of your vector `deck` in the constructor. But when you call the constructor your `deck` vector is empty

```
vector <BitCard> deck={}; // <- empty deck 

DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards(){
    for (int i = 0; i <numberOfCards;++i){
        deck[i].face = i%faces; // <- At construction time, you are trying to access deck with index i. but Deck is empty!
        //...
    }
}
```

One solution is to construct your object `BitCard` and push it to the `vector`

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards(){
    for (int i = 0; i <numberOfCards;++i){
        BitCard myBitCard;
        myBitCard.face = i%faces;
        myBitCard.suit = i/faces;
        myBitCard.color = i/(faces*colors);
        deck.push_back(myBitCard);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of your `deck` vector is always 0.  Using `[]` to index a vector **won't** automatically resize the vector to accommodate an invalid index.

You could initialize it to the correct size.

```
vector <BitCard> deck(numberOfCards);
```

Or resize it in the constructor.

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards(){
    deck.resize(numberOfCards);
```

Or you can use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) in the constructor's loop to add each new card to the end of the vector.

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards(){
    for (int i = 0; i <numberOfCards;++i){
        BitCard card;
        card.face = i%faces;
        card.suit = i/faces;
        card.color = i/(faces*colors);
        deck.push_back( card )
    }
}
```

Comment: Resizing it in the constructor worked. Thanks a lot!